# Best practices for base controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my old days when  I was an asp.net webforms developer I used to create a basepage and in there I used to put common methods and properties that would be used in the application, then every page would inherit from that page.

I wonder how to do it for mvc 4, is there any guideline, or just create a base controller class and inherit all controllers from that class?

What do you usually put in the base controller class?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I avoid using a base controller (inheritance) for this problem, because it kinda smells. Are you sure your controllers need ALL those common methods and properties? At least some of the functionality can be implemented as extension methods on the Controller type.

Also other functionality might be more suitable as a service injected into the controller. For common methods that require some (request)state I prefer the service approach.

It's also possible that at least some functionality to belong to an action filter (checking rights, setting some user profile, handling exceptions ;) etc ).

As a thumb rule, I try to avoid using inheritance with my controllers. The controllers should be as simple as they can be and any utility behavior I'd need, I try to encapsulate it in one of the ways presented above.

Comment: I really like the idea of extension methods in the controller type, its amazing.  However I dont understand the concept of a service injected into a controller and action filters?.  About the controllers inheritance, I liked the idea of creating a Basecontroller  and override the OnException method only to log with LogN, I dont think you can log all exceptions easily without using a base controller, can you?

Comment: what u think about the logging on the onexception in base controller? as I commented above

Comment: Asp.net mvc has the HandleErrorAttribute which I think is enabled by default for all controllers. You can subclass it to create your own exception attribute  and override OnException to login using Nlog. Btw, a Controller is automatically an IExceptionFilter in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really much a practise doing this. A lot of people coming from years of web forms think this way.

In our pretty big application, we created a `BaseController` but didn't really see a way to encapsulate common behaviour into it.

**However**, eventually we did put a some common code to log exceptions by overriding the [OnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method in a *base controller*

So I think you should go by : *If you see code you can encapsulate, do it*. You can make private methods inside the base controller **but** you cannot create a common action method in your base controller. You need to just encapsulate the code in a protected method, then you'll need an individual Action method in your concrete controller.